# pagination and filter separately running / Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I fetch and do pagination on the data, no problem with that. But when I try to filter the data, the pagination not working with the filtered data. Still displaying next pages at bottom. And when I go(for example) page 2 there is no data in page two. Because I filtered it already. How can I fix this problem? Thank you!

**Index Component**

```js
Data(){
    meta_data: {
          last_page: null,
          current_page: 1,
          prev_page_url: null
     }
},
methods: {
    fetchEstates(page = 1){
        axios.get('/ajax', {
            params: {
                page
            }}).then((response) => {
                // console.log(response);
                this.estates = response.data.data;
                this.insertMarkers();
                this.meta_data.last_page = response.data.last_page;
                this.meta_data.current_page = response.data.current_page;
                this.meta_data.prev_page_url = response.data.prev_page_url;
        });
    },
},

computed: {
    one: function () {
        let filteredStates = this.estates.filter((estate) => {
            return (this.keyword.length === 0 || estate.address.includes(this.keyword)) &&
            (this.rooms.length === 0 || this.rooms.includes(estate.rooms)) &&
            (this.regions.length === 0 || this.regions.includes(estate.region))});

            if(this.sortType == 'price') {
                filteredStates = filteredStates.sort((prev, curr) => prev.price - curr.price);
            }
            if(this.sortType == 'created_at') {
                filteredStates = filteredStates.sort((prev, curr) => Date.parse(curr.created_at) - Date.parse(prev.created_at));
            }

            filteredStates = filteredStates.filter((estate) => { return estate.price <= this.slider.value});
            filteredStates = filteredStates.filter((estate) => { return estate.extend <= this.sliderX.value});
            filteredStates = filteredStates.filter((estate) => { return estate.m2_price <= this.sliderT.value});

            return filteredStates;
    },
}
```

```html
<pagination
      :meta_data="meta_data"
      v-on:next="fetchEstates">
</pagination>
```

**Pagination Component**

```js
    props: ['meta_data'],
    methods: {
        next(page) {
            this.$emit('next', page);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
    <nav>
         <ul class="pagination pagination-lg">
             <li class="page-item"
                 :class="{ 'disabled': meta_data.prev_page_url === null }">
                 <a href="#"
                     class="page-link"
                     @click="next(meta_data.current_page-1)">
                     &laquo;
                 </a>
             </li>
             <li class="page-item"
                 v-for="page in meta_data.last_page"
                 :key="page"
                 :class="{ 'active':meta_data.current_page === page }">
                 <a href="#"
                     @click.prevent="next(page)"
                     class="page-link">
                     {{ page }}
                 </a>
             </li>
             <li class="page-item"
                 :class="{ 'disabled': meta_data.current_page === meta_data.last_page }">
                <a  href="#"
                     class="page-link"
                     @click="next(meta_data.current_page+1)">
                     &raquo;
                </a>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: The concept is wrong here, you are filtering after pagination, but you should paginate the filtered results. Say you have 30 estates, server returns 10 of em for page 1, you are filtering it to show 3 results on the 1st page. You should filter the results first, then distribute them into pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong you should send the data to backend/sql then filter them there.
so you get the right `last_page` etc.

Anyway if you still want to filter them as its is, you will need to calculate the pages agen.

Here is a sample, so you could calculate how many pages in `filteredStates` and generate pages, you may already able to generate them but the calculation could help you.

```js
Data(){
// you should use data only :) eg data:function()  { return  meta_data }
// but if this work for you i gusse its fine.
    meta_data: {
          totalPages: null,
          current_page: 1,
          pageSize: 20,// how many items exist per page
          pagedItems: [], // paged items eg when you click prev or next
          filteredData:[], // total items
          prevClass: "",
          nextClass: "",
          pages:[]
         
     }
},
methods: {
    // this will init the paginations and display the data
    getData: function(){
    // totalpages 
      this.meta_data.totalPages = Math.ceil(this.meta_data.filteredData.length / this.meta_data.pageSize);
       // items for the current selected Page
       this.meta_data.pagedItems = 
       this.meta_data.filteredData.slice(this.meta_data.pageSize * (this.meta_data.current_page -1),this.meta_data.pageSize);
       
       if (this.meta_data.current_page == this.meta_data.totalPages
       || this.meta_data.totalPages <=1)
           this.meta_data.nextClass = "disabled";
           else this.meta_data.nextClass = "";
           
      if (this.meta_data.current_page <=1)
           this.meta_data.prevClass = "disabled";
           else this.meta_data.prevClass = "";
           
           this.calPages();
     
    },
    
    toPage:function(page){
      this.meta_data.current_page = page;
      this.getData();
    },
    
    next: function(){
     if (this.meta_data.totalPages >= this.meta_data.current_page +1){
         this.meta_data.current_page++;
         this.getData();
         }
         
        return false;
    },
    
    prev: function(){
     if (this.meta_data.current_page -1 >=1 ){
          this.meta_data.current_page--;
          this.getData();
         }
         
        return false;
    },
    // this will generate [counter] pages each time you select a page.
    // I wrote this a long time ago for one of my application
    calPages: function(){
      if (this.meta_data.totalPages<=0)
          return false;
      var start = this.meta_data.current_page;
   var end = this.meta_data.current_page;
   var counter = 3;
      //If the page cannot be devised by counter enter the loop
   if ((start % counter != 0) && (end % counter != 0)) {
    //Get the next nearest page that is divisible by 5
    while ((end % counter) != 0) {
     end++;
    }
    //Get the previous nearest page that is divisible by counter
    while ((start % counter) != 0) {
     start--;
    }

   }
   //The page is divisible by counter so get the next counter pages in the pagination
   else {
    end += counter;
   }
   //We are on the first page
   if (start == 0) {
      start++;
      end++;
   }



   //We are on the last page
   if (end == this.meta_data.totalPages || end > this.meta_data.totalPages) {
    end = this.meta_data.totalPages ;
   }

   if (start == this.meta_data.current_page && start > 1)
    start--;

   while (end - start < counter && end - start > 0)
    start--;


   if (start <= 0)
    start = 1;

   while (end - start > counter)
    end--;
       var r =[];
       
       for (var i = start; i <= end; i++)
            r.push({ page:i, selected:(this.meta_data.current_page == i? "selected" : "") });
            
          this.meta_data.pages = r;
    }

    fetchEstates(page = 1){
        axios.get('/ajax', {
            params: {
                page
            }}).then((response) => {
                // console.log(response);
                this.estates = response.data.data;
                this.insertMarkers();
                //this.meta_data.last_page = response.data.last_page;
                //this.meta_data.current_page = response.data.current_page;
                //this.meta_data.prev_page_url = response.data.prev_page_url;
        });
    },
},

computed: {
    // dont see where you are calling this?
    one: function () {
        let filteredStates = this.estates.filter((estate) => {
            return (this.keyword.length === 0 || estate.address.includes(this.keyword)) &&
            (this.rooms.length === 0 || this.rooms.includes(estate.rooms)) &&
            (this.regions.length === 0 || this.regions.includes(estate.region))});

            if(this.sortType == 'price') {
                filteredStates = filteredStates.sort((prev, curr) => prev.price - curr.price);
            }
            if(this.sortType == 'created_at') {
                filteredStates = filteredStates.sort((prev, curr) => Date.parse(curr.created_at) - Date.parse(prev.created_at));
            }

            filteredStates = filteredStates.filter((estate) => { return estate.price <= this.slider.value});
            filteredStates = filteredStates.filter((estate) => { return estate.extend <= this.sliderX.value});
            filteredStates = filteredStates.filter((estate) => { return estate.m2_price <= this.sliderT.value});
            
this.meta_data.filteredData = filteredStates;
this. getData()// this will init the paginations and display the data 
return filteredStates;
    },
}
```

```html
 <nav>
         <ul class="pagination pagination-lg">
             <li class="page-item"
                 :class="meta_data.prevClass">
                 <a href="#"
                     class="page-link"
                     v-on:click="prev">
                     &laquo;
                 </a>
             </li>
             <li class="page-item"
                 v-for="page in meta_data.pages" :key="page"
                 :class="page.selected">
                 <a href="#"
                     v-on:click="toPage(page.page)"
                     class="page-link">
                     {{ page.page }}
                 </a>
             </li>
             <li class="page-item" :class="meta_data.prevClass" v-on:click="next" >
                <a href="#"
                     class="page-link"
                     @click="next">
                     &raquo;
                </a>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but it's not a understandable one. additionally, it's completely different code that I used in the question, but also not clear?... Actually, it would really good for a better explanation, and codes which are directly using my code to understand what's wrong...

Comment: I could rewrite your code, but you will need to get all the data from the api, that mean these `this.meta_data.last_page = response.data.last_page` etc will not be used anymore, is that ok for you ? otherwise you need to filter the data at the api.

Comment: in the end if I do filter and paginate the data without a problem. then very welcome for that... the problem here, my other functions(for example, **map marker** or **pagination**) running separatly with filter function. in the end I want to learn how to fix this problem... I am okay to give it a try for you rewrite... Thank you for helping me out. Appriciate it.

Comment: Here i rewrote it, make sure to read the comment and understand the idee. this code is not tested so you may incounter some bugs. But the code i wrote should work.

Comment: thanks for the edit, it made solved a couple problem. appreciate it!

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Comment: if you have time, could you check this question out too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54646065/making-load-more-function-in-vue/54651274#54651274

Answer (score 0):

Hello I'm not sure you are going about this in the best way. I have recently done something similar. Below is my simplified code:

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
    <table>
      <thead>
       <tr>
      <th>Index</th>
      <th>Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="item, index in filterItems" v-if="index >= pagestart && index <= pageend">
      <td>{{index}}</td>
      <td>{{item}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <ul class="pagination" style="padding:20px;">
        <li><a @click="pagination(pagecurrent - 1)">‹</a></li>
        <li v-for="index in pagipages" @click="pagination(index)" :class="{active:index == pagecurrent}"><a>{{index}}</a></li>
        <li><a @click="pagination(pagecurrent + 1)">›</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

VUE:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
    data () {
        return {
            items: [],
            pagecurrent: 1,
            pagestart: 0,
            pageend: 25,
            itemsperpage: 25,
        }
    },
    methods:{
        pagination: function pagination(index) {
            //This calculates the range of data to show depending on the selected page
            if (index > 0 && index <= this.pagipages) {
                this.pagecurrent = index;
                this.pagestart = (this.itemsperpage * index) - this.itemsperpage;
                this.pageend = (this.itemsperpage * index);
            }
        },
    },
    computed: {
        filterItems: function filterItems() {
            var filter = this.items;
            //Do Filtering here
            return filter;
        },
        pagipages: function pagipage() {
            //This calculates the amount of pages
            return Math.ceil(this.filterItems.length / this.itemsperpage);
        }
    },

    watch: {
        //This resets the data for when the filter is changed
        filterItems: function() {
            this.pagecurrent = 1;
            this.pagestart = 0;
            this.pageend = this.itemsperpage;
        }
    }
})
```