# Making load more function in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Trying to make a load more button, when user click it add 10 more item into the page. But the button code is not running smoothly... I still see all items in the page, and also there is no error in the console too.. of course button is not working.

Additionally, trying to make it run with the filter function.. Thank you for any example, help.

```js
data() {
        return {
            estates:[],
            moreEstates: [],
            moreEstFetched: false,
        }
},

mounted() {
        axios.get('/ajax').then((response) => {
            this.estates = response.data
            this.insertMarkers();

        });
},

methods: {
        handleButton: function () {
            if(!this.moreEstFetched){
                axios.get('/ajax').then((response) => {
                    this.moreEstates = response.data;
                    this.estates = this.moreEstates.splice(0, 10);
                    this.moreEstFetched = true;
                });
            }
            var nextEsts = this.moreEstFetched.splice(0, 10);
            
            this.estates.push(nextEsts);
        },
},

computed: {
        one: function () {
            let filteredStates = this.estates.filter((estate) => {
                return (this.keyword.length === 0 || estate.address.includes(this.keyword)) &&
                (this.rooms.length === 0 || this.rooms.includes(estate.rooms)) &&
                (this.regions.length === 0 || this.regions.includes(estate.region))});

                if(this.sortType == 'price') {
                    filteredStates = filteredStates.sort((prev, curr) => prev.price - curr.price);
                }
                if(this.sortType == 'created_at') {
                    filteredStates = filteredStates.sort((prev, curr) => Date.parse(curr.created_at) - Date.parse(prev.created_at));
                }

                filteredStates = filteredStates.filter((estate) => { return estate.price <= this.slider.value});
                filteredStates = filteredStates.filter((estate) => { return estate.extend <= this.sliderX.value});
                filteredStates = filteredStates.filter((estate) => { return estate.m2_price <= this.sliderT.value});

                return filteredStates;
        },
},
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr style="background-color: #fff ">
            <th scope="col">イメージ</th>
            <th style="width:175px;"scope="col">物件名</th>
            <th style="width:175px;"scope="col">住所</th>
            <th scope="col">販売価格</th>
            <th scope="col">間取り</th>
            <th scope="col">専有面積</th>
            <th scope="col">坪単価</th>
            <th style="width:90px;" scope="col">物件詳細</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
        <tr　 v-for="estate in one">
            <td><img id="image" :src="estate.image" alt=""></td>
            <td>{{estate.building_name}}</td>
            <td>{{estate.address}}</td>
            <td>{{priceSep(estate.price)}} 万円</td>
            <td>{{estate.rooms}}</td>
            <td>{{xtendSep(estate.extend)}} m²</td>
            <td>{{estate.m2_price}}</td>
            <td><a :href="/pages/+estate.id">物件詳細</a></td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button class="btn btn-primary loadmorebutton" @click="handleButton">Load more</button>
```

Comment: I don't see any data in your component called `one`. Where is `v-for="estate in one"` coming from?

Comment: 1. `var nextEsts = this.moreEstFetched.splice(0, 10);` => `moreEstFetched` is a boolean...  
2. The axios request in `handleButton` is async, so when the two lines after the if-statement are executed the data axios is fetching has not yet arrived ...

Comment: thank you for pointing out, any idea how to fix that? :) @pyriand3r

Answer (score 0):

As @pyriand3r pointed out that the axios request is async you can do something like this with async/await without modifiyng too much the code.

```
methods: {
  handleButton: function () {
      if(!this.moreEstFetched){
           axios.get('/ajax').then(async (response) => {
              this.moreEstates = await response.data;
              this.estates = this.moreEstates.splice(0, 10);
              this.moreEstFetched = true;
          });
      }
// Also you cant splice a boolean only arrays.
      var nextEsts = this.moreEstFetched.splice(0, 10);

      this.estates.push(nextEsts);
  },
},
```

[See: Async/await in JavaScript](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-async-await-in-javascript-1d81bb079b2c)

Comment: In the this.moreEstates asignation?

Comment: thank you for the answer. actually, overcome to @pyriand3r pointed out problem. I insert the handleButton() into mounted. then I can hide the items... but the button is not working... also I tried your answer but, it says `await is reserved word` in `moreEstate` part.

Comment: thank you for the update. now Having this error: `this.moreEstFetched.splice is not a function`

Comment: Yes, that's because the splice method can only be used on arrays, you are trying to splice a boolean.
[Array splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: hmm,  I tried your fix, first it showing all the items. and then I click the buttons, hide all just showing 10 :)) looks like running but reverse... hmmm

Comment: As in the code above this.moreEstFetched is boolean, and this.moreEstates is an array.

Comment: Splice do exactly what you are looking for, it gives you a certain amount of items from an array, you are specifying that it gives you 0 to 10 items.

Comment: So whats your issue now? Hiding when clicking?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188287/discussion-between-barbie-and-luis-maldonado).

Comment: yes i did, shared the answer  also... and really thank you so much for helping me out. :)

Comment: Anytime, glad I could help somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes to your code, read the comment to understand.

But this is the same as the last [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54565731/pagination-and-filter-separately-running-vue/54641720?noredirect=1#comment96112745_54641720) you added.

```js
data() {
        return {
            visible:true ,
            estates:[],
            moreEstates: [],
            moreEstFetched: false,
            size: 10,
            selectedPage:0,
            init: false,
            
        }
},
updated: function () { // when loaded, trigger only once
            if (!this.init) {
                this.handleButton();
                this.init = true;
            }
        },
mounted() {
// why is this here, you should only have handleButton to load the data
       // axios.get('/ajax').then((response) => {
        //    this.estates =this.filterData(response.data)
          //  this.insertMarkers();
          //  this.showMore();
     //   });
},

methods: {

        filterData: function (data) {
let filteredStates = data.filter((estate) => {
                return (this.keyword.length === 0 || estate.address.includes(this.keyword)) &&
                (this.rooms.length === 0 || this.rooms.includes(estate.rooms)) &&
                (this.regions.length === 0 || this.regions.includes(estate.region))});

                if(this.sortType == 'price') {
                    filteredStates = filteredStates.sort((prev, curr) => prev.price - curr.price);
                }
                if(this.sortType == 'created_at') {
                    filteredStates = filteredStates.sort((prev, curr) => Date.parse(curr.created_at) - Date.parse(prev.created_at));
                }

                filteredStates = filteredStates.filter((estate) => { return estate.price <= this.slider.value});
                filteredStates = filteredStates.filter((estate) => { return estate.extend <= this.sliderX.value});
                filteredStates = filteredStates.filter((estate) => { return estate.m2_price <= this.sliderT.value});

return filteredStates;
        },
        showMore: function(){
                    if (Math.ceil( this.moreEstates.length / this.size) <= this.selectedPage +1 ){
            this.selectedPage++;
            
       // using slice is better where splice changes the orginal array
            var nextEsts = this.moreEstFetched.slice((this.selectedPage * this.size), this.size);
            
            this.estates.push(nextEsts);
           }else this. visible= true; // hide show more
        
        },

        handleButton: function () {
            if(!this.moreEstFetched){
                axios.get('/ajax').then((response) => {
                    // filter the whole data at once
                    this.moreEstates = this.filterData(response.data);
                    this.moreEstFetched = true;
                    // not sure what this is, i moved it here 
                    this.insertMarkers(); 
                    this.showMore();
                });
            }else this.showMore();
        },
},
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr style="background-color: #fff ">
            <th scope="col">イメージ</th>
            <th style="width:175px;"scope="col">物件名</th>
            <th style="width:175px;"scope="col">住所</th>
            <th scope="col">販売価格</th>
            <th scope="col">間取り</th>
            <th scope="col">専有面積</th>
            <th scope="col">坪単価</th>
            <th style="width:90px;" scope="col">物件詳細</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
        <tr v-for="estate in estates">
            <td><img id="image" :src="estate.image" alt=""></td>
            <td>{{estate.building_name}}</td>
            <td>{{estate.address}}</td>
            <td>{{priceSep(estate.price)}} 万円</td>
            <td>{{estate.rooms}}</td>
            <td>{{xtendSep(estate.extend)}} m²</td>
            <td>{{estate.m2_price}}</td>
            <td><a :href="/pages/+estate.id">物件詳細</a></td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button v-if="visible" class="btn btn-primary loadmorebutton" @click="handleButton">Load more</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

actually, I am not sure it is the best way but, tried much more simplest way to achieve it...

```js
data() {
    return {
        moreEstates: 10,
    }
},
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tbody>
        <tr v-if="moreIndex < one.length"　 v-for="moreIndex in moreEstates">
            <td><img id="image" :src="one[moreIndex].image" alt=""></td>
            <td>{{one[moreIndex].building_name}}</td>
            <td>{{one[moreIndex].address}}</td>
            <td>{{priceSep(one[moreIndex].price)}} 万円</td>
            <td>{{one[moreIndex].rooms}}</td>
            <td>{{xtendSep(one[moreIndex].extend)}} m²</td>
            <td>{{one[moreIndex].m2_price}}</td>
            <td><a :href="/pages/+one[moreIndex].id">物件詳細</a></td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button class="btn btn-primary loadmorebutton" @click="moreEstates += 10">次の10件を見る</button>
```